# Pyodbc query works in a functional format, but yields Windows Fatal Exception when implemented in an Object Oriented manner

Tags: python-3.x, pyodbc

I am querying multiple SQL databases and combining them into a single table.  For the purposes of this discussion I am using pseudo-code to describe the queries, because I do not want to give information publicly about the database.  However, the query is not the issue so it should not be a problem for this example.

To first ensure that the code works correctly, I implemented a functional version of it in a Jupiter notebook.  The code I used is shown below and it works just fine when the actual query is inserted.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

# This code works in Jupyter notebook using a Python 3.8
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={XXXX};"
                      "Server=XXXX;"
                      "uid=XXXX;"
                      "pwd=XXXX")
df = pd.read_sql_query("query goes here", conn)
```

My next step was to implement the code in actual `.py` files as object oriented code, which is shown below.

```
class OpenDB:
def __init__(self):
    # - will pass variables in class instantiation once
    #   I get the classes working correctly
    self.conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={XXXX};"
                               "Server=XXXX;"
                               "uid=XXXX;"
                               "pwd=XXXX")
    self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

def close_database_connection(self) -> None:
    self.conn.close()
    return
# ============================================================================
# ============================================================================


class ReadDB(OpenDB):
    def __init__(self):
        OpenDB.__init__(self)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    def read_data(self) -> pd.DataFrame:
        df = pd.read_sql_query("query goes here", self.conn)
        # - The code fails after the above line and never gets to 
        #   the line below this
        self.close_database_connection()
        return df
# ============================================================================
# ============================================================================

db = ReadDB()
df = db.read_data()
```

The object oriented code written above appears to be the exact same code used in the Jupiter notebook; however, when I run it as shown above, the query fails and returns the error `Windows fatal exception: access violation error`.  The queries are identical between the two implementations, and the information passed to establish the database connection is identical.  Can anyone see why the Jupiter notebook implementation works and the object oriented version does not?  Both are using Python 3.8.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue under Python 3.7.5 64-bit on Windows. I copied your code verbatim and it worked fine for me with ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server. What ODBC driver are you using?

Comment: @GordThompson I am using SQL server native client 11.0

Comment: Your code also works for me with `DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0`